# Javascript cannot read input value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, input

My input value is not being read by my javascript. First problem is because the input value has integrate with autoload `div`. If I use a pure input value it works, but if the input is integrated with the autoload `div` it stops working.

**Here's my php code:**

```
<form method="post" action="" target="_parent">
        <h4 style="color: grey; font-size: 30px; margin: auto;"><b>Jumlah Diterima</b></h4>
        <div class="input-control">
                <input type="text" name="amt" id="amt" style="width:300px; font-size: 30px; height: 50px; font-weight: bold;  margin: auto; color:grey;">
        </div><br/><br/><br/>
        <h4 style="color: grey; font-size: 30px; margin: auto;"><b>Jumlah Tagihan</b></h4><br><br>
        <h4 style="color: grey; font-size: 30px; margin: auto;"><b>Rp. <?php echo $nominal; ?>,-</b></h4>
        <input type="text" id="nominal" name="nominal" value="1000">
        <br><br><br><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Selesai" style="background: #1ba1e2; border-color: #1ba1e2; height: 70px; font-weight: bold;  margin-left: 150px; width:280px; font-size: 30px;" class="button primary" />
        </div>
```

**Here's my javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.slim.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$jq(function() {
    var money = 7000;

    $jq("#nominal").on("change keyup", function() {
        var input = $jq(this);

        // remove possible existing message
        if( input.next().is("form") )
            input.next().remove();

        // show message
        if( input.val() > money )
            input.after("<form method=\"post\" action=\"\"><input type=\"submit\" name=\"yes\" value=\"Yes\"><input type=\"submit\" name=\"no\" value=\"No\"></form>");
    });
});
</script>
<script>
function loadValue5() {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'grab_count_old.php',
        success: function(responseText) {
            $('#amt').fadeOut('fast', function () {
                $('#amt').val(responseText).fadeIn('fast', function() {
                    setTimeout(loadValue5, 100);
                });
            });
        }
    });
}
loadValue5();
</script>
```

**Here's my `grab_count.php` (Autoload)**

```
<?php
include("../config/db_function.php");
db_function();

mysql_select_db("testpy") or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM datapy ORDER BY No DESC LIMIT 0,1")
or die(mysql_error());
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
           echo $row['nilai_1'];
        }

?>
```

In some cases, if change the `ID` in the javascript with `#nominal` (pure input) it will work, but if I change with `#amt` (input with autoload) it's not working. Any help would be appreciated on this, I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: lol why do you need 2 jquery files?

Comment: if i delete script it's not working, but forget that @madalinivascu

Comment: i don't see what you are trying to do , you are overiding the client input data each half of second why?

Comment: i have get value from auto load div and put it into input fill, my javascript will read value on input  fill but can't read. if my javascript can read input value then will show form @madalinivascu

Comment: the problem is, why my javascript cannot read input value with auto load div, any trick for solve?

Comment: appending a form in a form is not valid and your english is not that grate can't understand a word of it